# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, sql

i created a simple db connection in my php page and its working fine since its not showing any error while executing this

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('www.ccccccccccccc.co.uk', 'cccccccccc', 'accccc');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    /*echo 'Connected successfully';*/
    echo "DB : <font color='green'>ACTIVE</font>";

    mysql_close($link);
?>

The problem is the page is showing error Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) while executing 

<?php
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT slno, name, idno  FROM $memlist") or die(mysql_error());

    echo "<table><tr><th> NO</th><th> NAME</th>
            <th> ID NO</th></tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
        extract($row);

        echo "<tr><td>$slno</td><td>$name</td>
            <td>$idno</td></tr>";
    }
    echo"</table>";
?>
```

i am working on server directly not on local host

Comment: Do you include the code for opening the connection to your MySQL anywhere before sending the `SELECT ...`?

Comment: You are trying to connect to a remote server ?

Comment: Yes i am trying to connect to remote server ..

Comment: @Sirko yes ..are you talking about <?php
$link = mysql_connect('www.ccccccccccccc.co.uk', 'cccccccccc', 'accccc');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
/*echo 'Connected successfully';*/
echo "DB : <font color='green'>ACTIVE</font>";

mysql_close($link);
?>

Comment: removed mysql_close($link); from first piece of code,now its showing You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 –

Comment: I double check ed the sql connection,it works fine .. but the error is still showing up

Answer (score 6):

You don't appear to be connecting to the database in the second piece of code, so it's trying to connect with default settings (which obviously won't be correct due to security concerns).

As for the first block of code, you're closing the connection immediately after opening it, which is kind of pointless.

Comment: i removed mysql_close($link); from first piece of code,now its showing You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: That's because you appear to have dumped `$memlist` into the query, without even defining it.

Comment: Thanks can you please suggest a way to fix this..its very very important for me and short in time

Comment: Aneesh, it might actually take more time scrambling on stackoverflow than checking it yourself on internet. Here are some pages to help you out: http://php.net/mysql_connect, http://php.net/mysql_query, http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: I double check ed the sql connection,it works fine .. but the error is still showing up

Comment: Use `echo` to see what the query you're actually sending to MySQL is. I'm sure it'll look like `SELECT slno, name, idno  FROM ` which is invalid because you didn't say where to select from.